# how to solve the following in apache spark

Tags: java, apache-spark

Consider a retail scenario where an array of `(K,V)` input holds the (product name,price) as show below. Value of every Key need to be subtracted with `500` for discount offer

Use Spark logics to achieve the above requirement,

Input

`{(Jeans,2000),(Smart phone,10000),(Watch,3000)}`

Expected Output`enter code here`

`{(Jeans,1500),(Smart phone,9500),(Watch,2500)}`

I have tried the below code I'm getting errors please help me to fix them
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.Iterator;

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.FlatMapFunction;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function2;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.PairFunction;

import scala.Tuple2;

public class PairRDDAgg {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    SparkConf conf = new 
SparkConf().setAppName("Line_Count").setMaster("local");
    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

    JavaRDD<String> input = 
sc.textFile("C:/Users/xxxx/Documents/retail.txt");



    JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> counts = input.mapValues(new Function() {
        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public Integer call(Integer i) {
            return (i-500);
        }


    });

    System.out.println(counts.collect());

    sc.close();
}
}
```

Comment: At least try working on your homework a bit !

Comment: The code is not for me it's just how this site works

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I believe that you have accepted an answer. So this issue is closed for me ! I won't remove the downvote thought. There is nothing in that code beside one modified line. The other is generated by your IDE.

Comment: no prblm thanks for ur help @eliasah :)

Comment: can you help me with the reference links of apache spark with java @eliasah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
scala> val dataset = spark.createDataset(Seq(("Jeans",2000),("Smart phone",10000),("Watch",3000)))
dataset: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[(String, Int)] = [_1: string, _2: int]

scala> dataset.map ( x => (x._1, x._2 - 500) ).show

 +-----------+----+
 |         _1|  _2|
 +-----------+----+
 |      Jeans|1500|
 |Smart phone|9500| 
 |      Watch|2500|
 +-----------+----+
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you tell m how to do this in java

Answer (score 1):

Use mapValues() function

An example for your scenario would be

```
rdd.mapValues(x => x-500);
```